# Remove all occurences of specific text between single white spaces

Tags: javascript, typescript

I need to remove all occurencies of a text that is between white spaces. More specifically, left white space can only be a tab, the right white space can either be a tab, or a new line

Let's remove all occurrences of the word "dog" from between \t and \t or \n

Current state:

`"\tcat\tdog\tbird\tdog\n"`

Expected result

`"\tcat\t\tbird\t\n"`

What is this about: I am copying data from excel like grid, however, empty columns are copied as "null". I am trying to remove "null" in order for the copied column to be empty

Comment: Sounds like you want to remove all spaces?

Comment: @GetSet Hello, not really. I want to remove specific text "someText" only when is this text located between \t and \n or \t and \t

Comment: Hijacking your comments on @Marcos answer, you want to remove chars between \t and \n. But do you also want to remove those \t, \n chars also?

Comment: Only reason your question has gone on for hours like this is **you failed to detail your requirements**. One way to avoid this is to specify (in your question) a "before" and an "after". That is an example of "input" and "output".

Comment: @GetSet Thank you for helping me despite that. I specified current and expected result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I'm misreading your question, but it sure seems like you can accomplish this very easily doing...

```js
const str = '\tcat\tdog\tbird\tdog\n';
const new_str = str.replace(/\tdog\t/g, '\t\t').replace(/\tdog\n/g, '\t\n');
console.log(new_str);
```

Or, as MetallimaX aptly points out, you can do it in just one regex:

```js
const str = '\tcat\tdog\tbird\tdog\n';
const new_str = str.replace(/\tdog(\t|\n)/g, '\t$1');
console.log(new_str);
```

Comment: You can do it in one regex: `str.replace(/\tdog(\t|\n)/g, '\t$1');`

Answer (score 1):

Let's try this:

```
let s = '\tcat\tdog\tbird\tdog\n';
let ss = s.trim().split(/\t/);
let filtered = 'dog';
let fss = ss.map(item => item !== filtered ? item : '');
let res = '\t' + fss.join('\t') + '\n';
console.log(res);

// "\tcat\t\tbird\t\n"
```

Comment: Hello, that is very close but the tabs that were previously around "dog" should be preserved. I'll put spaces between characters to make it easily readable:
"\t cat \t \t bird \t \n"

Comment: @NevilleLobotom is it ok now?

Comment: Thank you this also works great. But I am using codemonkey's version so I accepted his/her answer. Sorry